# How to print data from database onto model popup box?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have books retrieved from database in the Index view. Each one has a button below. When you click them a modal box should pop up with the corresponding book details (book img, name title, decsription, price etc) printed on it.

Index View:

```
       <!-- language: lang-html -->
        @model AuthorTest.Models.HomeModel 


<!--razor codes where book properties are called-->
        @foreach(var book in Model.Bestsales) 
    {
        <a class="first__img" href="single-product.html"><img src="~/Uploads/img/@(book.Id + " .jpg ")"</a>
        <h4>product.html">@book.Name</a></h4>
        <ul class="prize d-flex">
           <li>@book.Price</li>
        </ul>
        <!--modal-box pop-up button-->
        <a data-toggle="modal" title="Quick View" data-id="@book.Id" class="modal-open" href="#productmodal"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></a> 
    }
```

I'm trying to  pass a book id  using ajax

```
<!-- language: lang-js-->
 @section scripts{
    <script> 
        $(".modal-open").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Details/" + id
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

into the "Details" action that retrieves related book and returns it to a view where modal box content is placed.

```
    <!-- language: lang-cs-->
     [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                HomeModel model = new HomeModel();
                var book = db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == id).Include(b => b.Author).SingleOrDefault();
                if (book == null)
                {
                    HttpNotFound();
                }

                book.DisplayNumber++;
                db.SaveChanges();
                model.bookDetails = book;
                return view( model);
           }
```

This is the HomeModel class that I use to keep two models 1)list property of type Book to loop through my books in the Index view
2)property of Book type to call model-related book datas in "Details" view:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs-->
public class HomeModel
{
    public List<Book> BestSales { get; set; }
    public Book bookDetails { get; set; }
}
```

a view where modal box content is placed:

```
<-- language: lang-html-->
@model AuthorTest.Models.HomeModel

   div id="quickview-wrapper">
    <!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="productmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal__container" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal__header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="modal-product">
                        <!-- Start product images -->
                        <div class="product-images">
                            <div class="main-image images">
                                <img alt="big images" src="~/Uploads/img/@(Model.bookDetails.Id + ".jpg")">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end product images -->
                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h1>@Model.bookDetails.Name</h1>
                            <div class="rating__and__review">

                            </div>
                            <div class="price-box-3">
                                <div class="s-price-box">
                                    <span class="new-price">@Model.bookDetails.Price</span>
                                    <span class="old-price">$34.00</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="quick-desc">
                                @Model.bookDetails.Description
                            </div>
                            <div class="addtocart-btn">
                                <a href="#">Add to cart</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When I click modal-open button the id gets passed to the "Details" action, corresponding book is retrieved and takes me to the view. But it seems like modal box pops up before ajax runs action and therefore the data is not printed. Where do I make mistake? How to pass the book details into the modal-box correctly?

Answer (score 2):

An Ajax call is asynchronous, so you must get in this mindset: when you work in a non sync way, you shall manage async calls with callbacks. jQuery offers different types of callback for the $.ajax() method, such as "success","error".... on and on. If the ajax call results in a server exception for instance, the HTTP result will be 500 and you can manage it in the "error" callback subscribing the callback with a your custom method that will be raised by jQuery. On the other way, the success callback must be subscribed by a method that accepts parameters where will be the server response (in this case, an html response). So, if the result is a success (HTTP Status code 200), you will have the HTML in that parameter, and you can use it to append in your modal (always with jQuery methods... or even in simple javascript if you like more)
Take a look to callbacks subscriptions:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ in the "Callback Function Queues" section. You will find out that I gave you just a real basic explanation and there's a lot of more to learn!